# Shared folder does not appear in guest CentOS (Windows host), using VMWare

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, vmware

I've been trying to share a folder between my guest, Cent OS, and host, Windows 10, using VMWare Workstation 14 Player. The easiest way, drag&dropping files from host to guest, does not work properly, as one or more files always ends up being of a smaller file size and thus corrupted, even though there is enough storage space in the virtual machine.

Then I have done the steps below to enable folder sharing from the host to the guest OS:

**HOST WINDOWS 10**

- Shared the folder with everyone (to assure that there is no permit limitations with my files)

**GUEST CENT OS**

- VM -> Settings -> Options -> Shared Folders. And added my folder.
- As per the suggestion of several posts on here, I've run vmware-config-tools.pl multiple times, e.g.:

  `sudo vmware-config-tools.pl -d --clobber-kernel-modules=vmhgfs`

..but **the `/mnt/hgfs` folder, where my shared folder was meant to appear, remains empty!**

I have gone through the VMware manual, and I am sure that I have followed their requirements. I am still not sure the VMware tools are installed completely, since typing `vmware-hgsclient` in the guest OS terminal returns the error "command not found".

Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like there's missing `f` in your command: `vmware-hgsclient`

Answer (score 7):

Prerequisites:

- open-vm-tools version is at 10.0.0 or greater
- OS supports fuse
- Kernel version >= 3.10 (if open-vm-tools < 10.3.0. kernel version must be >= 4.0)
- Supports systemd

Procedure:

1. Remove any extra files from the `/mnt/hgfs/` directory (if no other shared folders, the command `rm -rf /mnt/hgfs/*` works and worked for me)
2. Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-hgfs.mount` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=VMware mount for hgfs
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=umount.target
ConditionVirtualization=vmware
After=sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount

[Mount]
What=vmhgfs-fuse
Where=/mnt/hgfs
Type=fuse
Options=default_permissions,allow_other

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Add to or create the file `/etc/modules-load.d/open-vm-tools.conf` with this content:

```
fuse
```

4. Enable the systemd service with the command: `sudo systemctl enable mnt-hgfs.mount`
   This will make sure the hgfs fdirectory will be mounted after a reboot.
5. Make sure the 'fuse' module is loaded: `sudo modprobe -v fuse`
6. In Workstation or Fusion, enable *"Shared Folders"* in *"Virtual Machine Settings" > "Options"*, and set the folders to be shared.
7. The shared folders should appear in the directory `/mnt/hgfs`. If that is not the case, start the service with: `sudo systemctl start mnt-hgfs.mount` or reboot.

The details/source information is here: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/74650

Comment: I can confirm this solution worked like a charm. Stephen is a gentleman!

Comment: @Nickon I am glad that my answer was able to help you! Is the Stephen that are you talking about in your comment Stephen Kitt?

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to create a folder where the mount should be pointed to.

```
sudo mkdir /your_shared_folder
```

Then you should see your vmware shared folder using this command:

```
sudo vmware-hgfsclient
```

If you do see your shared folder then running this should mount your vmware shared folder to the folder you previously created:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse /your_shared_folder
```

Comment: I tried this in Parrot OS, worked as it is a Debian, sudo less.

Comment: how come `vmhgfs-fuse` help says it takes two arguments and you're giving syntax with the only one?

Answer (score 4):

I simply used the solution from this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/gb53f1/ubuntu_2004vmware_1550_shared_folders_not_visible/g5k8caf?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/hgfs
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```